# Self hosted speech to text software on linux with gui?

Tags: linux, speech-recognition, debian

I want to make it so the hours and hours of notes to self I have can be turned into easily searchable text without sending them off to some third party to be processed. Should work on an offline machine that never touches the internet once its setup.

CMU Sphinx, Julius, Kaldi, Mozilla DeepSpeech are to complicated for me to use. I need an out of the box solution with a gui that just works, please.

I use debian 10.